# Node.js, After inserting not shown in list query

Tags: mysql, node.js, database

After adding a product to the mysql database, I want to dump all the products with the latest product. This product is being added with an algorithm to the database and I want to list all the products immediately afterwards. Already tried "async", "promise" etc.

--When the table **is empty**--

```
connection.query("INSERT INTO `products` (id, name, price)", function (error, results, fields) {}); //inserted one row

connection.query("SELECT * FROM `products`", function (error, results, fields) {}); // show only []
```

**after second insertion** list query **show only first row but not second**. The main problem is this and table has two rows.

Thank you.

Comment: How are you passing the data to the query, in other words, how are you specifying what to insert?  Also, pretty sure you don't need the ` marks around your table's name, but that's just a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Query data when insert is done:

```
connection.query("INSERT INTO `products` (id, name, price)",
  function (error, results, fields) {
      connection.query("SELECT * FROM `products`", function (error2, results2, fields2){});
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I already tried this and can't pass to a variable results2. How can handle results2 to a variable, is it possible?

Comment: @jakari `results2` _is_ a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
connection.query("INSERT INTO products(id, name, price)",
  function (error, results, fields) {
     if(error) return ....
     else{
       connection.query("SELECT * FROM products", function 
        (error,results,fields2){
               var returned_data = results; 
               console.log(results);
               //res.send(results); 
           })
   }});
```

Would be the way to go, ***but check whether you're inserting the data the right way at all***, since you haven't provided the way you do it, I doubt that any async method would fail you itself.

EDIT on request: You can pass the results to a variable, but you can only use it inside that function if you don't (because of its ***scope***) , ie res.send or res.end it (if you're using this inside a request, which I'm guessing you are), or console.log it or just write it to a file.

Comment: Thank you, Do you know any method for "second query result" pass to a variable?